# Laravel relation issue

Tags: php, laravel, model, laravel-blade

I have problem with getting products options they show in separate fields instead of being grouped.

## Logic

1. Option group gets type and values
2. Options belongs to groups also to products
3. Products gets Options

## Models

`Product`

```
public function options(){
  return $this->belongsToMany(Option::class, 'product_options', 'product_id', 'option_id');
}
```

`Option Group`

```
public function values(){
  return $this->hasMany(Option::class, 'option_id');
}
```

`Option`

```
public function group(){
  return $this->belongsTo(OptionGroup::class, 'option_id');
}

public function products(){
  return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class);
}
```

## Blade view

```
@if(count($product->options)>0)
<!-- options -->
<div class="tt-swatches-container">
    <div class="tt-wrapper">
    @foreach($product->options as $option)
        <div class="tt-title-options">{{$option->group->title}}:</div>
        @if($option->group->type == 'color')
            <ul class="tt-options-swatch options-large">
                <li><a class="options-color" style="background-color: {{$option->color}}" href="#"></a></li>
            </ul>
        @elseif($option->group->type == 'dropdown')
            <form class="form-default">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <select class="form-control">
                        <option>{{$option->title}}</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </form>
        @else
            <ul class="tt-options-swatch options-large">
                <li><a href="#">{{$option->title}}</a></li>
            </ul>
        @endif
    @endforeach
    </div>
</div>
<!-- options -->
@endif
```

## Results

[image: one]

As you see I have duplicated data in my view, colors must show in one group next to each other, and drop-down options must become one as well.

**Anyone can tell where I did mistake?**

## Update

I've added `mapToGroups` in my controller now results are much more cleaner but yet has issue with drop-down

`Controller`

```
$options = $product->options->mapToGroups(function ($item, $key) {
  return [$item->group->title => $item];
});
```

`Blade`

```
@if(count($options)>0)
<!-- options -->
<div class="tt-swatches-container">
    @foreach($options as $group => $option)
    <div class="tt-wrapper">
        <div class="tt-title-options">{{$group}}:</div>
        @foreach($option as $opt)
        @if($opt->group->type == 'color')
            <ul class="tt-options-swatch options-large">
                <li><a class="options-color" style="background-color: {{$opt->color}}" href="#"></a></li>
            </ul>
        @elseif($opt->group->type == 'dropdown')
            <form class="form-default">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <select class="form-control">
                         <option>{{$opt->title}}</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </form>
        @else
            <ul class="tt-options-swatch options-large">
                <li><a href="#">{{$opt->title}}</a></li>
            </ul>
        @endif
        @endforeach
    </div>
    @endforeach
</div>
<!-- options -->
@endif
```

## Result

[image: two]

Answer (score 1):

Your iteration is quiet wrong. What you are doing is creating a complete ul for each color, a complete select for each dropdown, and also a complete ul for each swatch.

easiest way to achieve your goal is using blade's magical [stacks](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/blade#stacks); We just push every option to it's own stack(color,dropdown,swatch) and finally print the stack:

```
@if(count($product->options)>0)
    @foreach($product->options as $option)
        @if($option->group->type == 'color')
            @push('color')
                <li>
                    <a class="options-color" style="background-color: {{$option->color}}" href="#"></a>
                </li>
            @endpush
        @elseif($option->group->type == 'dropdown')
            @push('dropdown')
                <option>{{$option->title}}</option>
            @endpush
        @else
            @push('swatch')
                <li>
                    <a href="#">{{$option->title}}</a>
                </li>
            @endpush
        @endif
    @endforeach
@endif


<div class="tt-swatches-container">
    <div class="tt-wrapper">
        <div class="tt-title-options">color:</div>
        <ul class="tt-options-swatch options-large">
            @stack('color')
        </ul>
        <div class="tt-title-options">option:</div>
        <form class="form-default">
            <div class="form-group">
                <select class="form-control">
                    @stack('dropdown')
                </select>
            </div>
        </form>
        @if($__env->yieldPushContent('swatch'))
           <div class="tt-title-options">swatch:</div>
           <ul class="tt-options-swatch options-large">
               @stack('swatch')
           </ul>
        @endif
    </div>
</div>
```

Good Luck.

Comment: hi, this helps but has a bit issue `screenshot =>` https://i.ibb.co/tKNFCqg/Screenshot.png

Comment: u can pass default value to @stack(NAME,DEFAULT). edited the code, check it again

Comment: the point is to not show it when there is no `swatch` and not to replace with another words.

Comment: The if part is to avoid printing empty options

Comment: unfortunately There is no  standard way to do this... but there is a hacky way

Comment: just edited, using $__env variable and internal laravel methods we can check if stack has content. fixed it for swatch, just repeat it for other two. good luck.